# "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" not working while requested URL makes another request (Cross Domain Rquest)

Tags: cross-domain

I added AllowOrigin custom attribue with requested controller action. Refer below function:

```
public class **AllowCrossSiteJsonAttribute** : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);<br>
        }
    }
    [**AllowCrossSiteJson**]
    public partial class OneBillSummaryController : UXPControllerBase
    {
        public OneBillSummaryController()
            : base(ApplicationType.Home,
                new QueryParameters() { appliesTo="Index", parameters=
                new Dictionary<string, QueryParameter>() { 
                { "BAN", new QueryParameter() },
                { "SeqNo", new QueryParameter() },
                { "CID", new QueryParameter() {values="cc,ss,r"} },
                { "Lang", new QueryParameter() {values="fr,en"}},
                { "TID", new QueryParameter(){isOptional=true} }
            }})
        {
        }
```

Till here, I was able to get result, but this action will do form authentication (already cookie exist in browser) and another URL/Controller-Action is going to call (Another URL request internally).

And I am stucking with below error. Refer below SS:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load 
>   **http://local-mybell-b.ids.int.bell.ca/UXP/Bill/OneBill/?BAN=101465254&SeqNo=0&CID=r&TID=&Lang=en**.
>   
> The request was redirected to
>   
> '**http://local-mybell-b.ids.int.bell.ca/sso/ssoauth.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fUXP%2fB…d0%26CID%3dr%26TID%3d%26Lang%3den&BAN=101465254&SeqNo=0&CID=r&TID=&Lang=en**',
>   
> which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require
>   preflight.

Added same CROS for that authentication action as well, but no luck.

Comment: Is any one have solution for above issue. Appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I got the answer Self, and posting the same.

Use **"Access-Control-Allow-Origin"** in **web-config or controller** level as per requirement and **Change the authentication mode** of web, As I disabled windows auth mode.

> Above code will work perfect, just while changing the Auth mode from configuration file.

Refer below SS.

[image]